# Place object at retina pixel location that standard resolution can't access?

Tags: ios, iphone, retina-display

I am animating something's position on the screen in xcode.

Currently it moves at "1" pixel every .1 seconds.

This means it's not moving at 1 pixel every .1 seconds on a retina display but 2 pixels every .1 seconds.

I want it to move at true 1 pixel every .1 seconds on a retina display. Is there any way to do this?

Any way to set an objects location to be a retina location or something?

Comment: Move the position by 0.5 points every .1 seconds? CGPoint is measured in points, not pixels.

Comment: Based on the comments you need to update the question with your actual code for doing the animation and setting the position of the views.

Comment: mind sharing some code ?

Answer (score 4):

You want to move in pixels. All coordinates in iOS are given in points. So you need to convert your points to pixels. This can be done by doing:

```
CGFloat screenScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
CGFloat ratio = 1.0 / screenScale;
```

Use `ratio` to increment your animation.

On a non-retina device, `ratio` will be `1` point. On current retina devices, `ratio` will be `0.5` point.

As you animate, move your x and y coordinates by `ratio` points and you will get one pixel of movement each time.

Comment: the issue isn't calculating the number of pixels. the issue is drawing at a pixel location

Comment: Now you use `ratio` to increment your `x` and `y` coordinates as you animate. The result will be pixel level movement appropriate to both types (retina and non-retina) of devices.

Comment: yeah I know. the issue isn't calculating the number of pixels!!!! The issue is that CGPointMake won't put something at 1.5 "points".....

Comment: Yes it will. Why do you say it won't? `CGPoint` is just two numbers. They can be anything. It's how the point is used that can matter.

Comment: You need to update your question with the actual code you are using to do the animation and set the position of the view. Otherwise we are all guessing at what it happening.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in iOS 4, dimensions are measured in “points” instead of pixels. In non-Retina screens a point is one pixel, and in Retina screens a point is two pixels, draw a one-point line and it shows up two pixels wide.

Therefore, when on Retina screens you can move `0.5` points (which will equal `1` pixel).

[image]

Have a look at [Apple's drawing concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/graphicsdrawingoverview/graphicsdrawingoverview.html).

Comment: So you're saying there's nothing I can do?

Comment: Well, I assume that you are managing actual pixels in your code? Try doing the same but with points.

Comment: That `pixelToPoints:` method has nothing at all to do with converting screen points to pixels.

Comment: The issue isn't calculating points or pixels or anything. I want to know how to place something at a pixel location not a point location.

Comment: You can just use fractional coordinates.